# Illegal instruction (core dumped) when import pandas. python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have Python 3.10.6 installed in my system (Lubuntu 22.04). I installed pandas and pyarrow with "pip3 install" command but when I try to import pandas in a .py file or even in the python3 console, like "import pandas as pd" or "import pandas" I get "Illegal instruction (core dumped)".

I tried to resintall pandas:

```
guilherme@guilherme-rv415:~$ pip3 install pandas
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas) (2022.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)
```

And python3:

```
guilherme@guilherme-rv415:~$ sudo apt-get install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.10.6-1~22.04).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But nothing has changed. I would like to know how can I fix this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: maybe try `pip install pandas`

Comment: I tried and I got the same result as pip3.

Comment: Then I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have installed pandas already. Remove it first, completely. Then install again.

After having removed, check if it is really gone. Do this with

```
find /usr -name "*pandas*"
```

and with

```
find ~/ -name "*pandas*"
```